# N-Queens without recursion (but with one goto)

Tags: c, n-queens

Compared to the recursive version e.g. on Rosetta, this is 5-10% faster and uses 50% less instructions (for N=12).

Only problem is the `goto`. Can it be avoided without using a function?

The two outer for-loops don't do much in terms of loop control. But this is how I could make it work.

Is there a more convincing non-recursive version? I searched quite a bit and most are recursive and/or longer.

```
/* N-Queens, non-recursive, with goto */
#include <stdio.h>
//const int N = 8;  //92 solutions
const int N = 12;   //14200 in 0.100 s

/* Print excluding last row, plus last col */
void pr_solution(int *bq, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
        printf("%d:", bq[i]);
    printf("%d\n", col);
}   
void init_board(int bq[], int v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        bq[i] = v;
}
int main() {
    int bq[N];
    init_board(bq, -1); 
    int row, col, rd, old;
    int cnt = 0;
    for (row = 0; row >= 0;) {
        
        for (col = bq[row];;) {
            NEXT_col:
            if (++col == N) 
                bq[row--] = -1;
            else {
                for (rd = 1; rd <= row; rd++)
                    if ((old = bq[row-rd]) == col || old == col+rd || old == col-rd)
                        goto NEXT_col;
                if (row == N - 1) {
                    cnt++;
                    row--;
                    //pr_solution(bq, col); 
                }
                else  
                    bq[row++] = col;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d SOLUTIONS (%dx%d)\n", cnt, N, N);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> Only problem is the goto. Can it be avoided without using a function?

Candidate `goto` replacement

```
    for (col = bq[row];;) {
        //NEXT_col: // Delete
        if (++col == N) 
            bq[row--] = -1;
        else {
            for (rd = 1; rd <= row; rd++)
                if ((old = bq[row-rd]) == col || old == col+rd || old == col-rd)
                    // goto NEXT_col;  // Delete
                    break; //ADD
            if (rd <= row) continue; // ADD
            if (row == N - 1) {
                cnt++;
                row--;
                //pr_solution(bq, col); 
            }
            else  
                bq[row++] = col;
        }
        break;
    }
```

`if (rd <= row) continue;` takes advantage that `for (col = bq[row];;)` lacks a test and increment.

> Is there a more convincing non-recursive version?

I'd re-write the loop (perhaps a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine))  - need some time to think about it.

---

**Later:**

Code as written is quite tight.  A *very nice* simple non-recursive solution.

Yet (at the risk of the ire of OP) lacks clarity making it unnecessarily  difficult to optimize.

The *style* uses terse variable names like `rd` and `bq` which do not well convey their meaning.  It is as if short variable names make faster code (it does not).  `init_board()` does not initialize a board, but a single dimension of data.  Use more meaningful names.

Use of incomplete `for` loops like `for (col = bq[row];;)` seems like a code golf goal than a clearer `col = bq[row]; while (1)`.

Helper functions like `pr_solution()` rely on the global `N`, which instead could be passed in, facilitating clearer function flow and allowing use with more than one size.

Local variable instantiation would help see their limited impact.

For clarity, use `{}` even for one-line blocks.

Consider rectangles, not only squares.  It adds clarity to code and offers other investigations for eventual optimization.

Some other ideas in code below too.

A first round cut:

```
int main(void) {
  for (int N = 1; N <= 8; N++) {
    const int ROW_N = N;
    const int COL_N = ROW_N;
    int queen_column[ROW_N];
    init_queen_column(ROW_N, queen_column, -1);
    long long count = 0;
    int parity[2] = { 0,0};
    int row = 0;
    while (row >= 0) {
      int col = queen_column[row];
      while (1) {
        if (++col == COL_N) {
          queen_column[row--] = -1;
        } else {
          int row_offset;
          for (row_offset = 1; row_offset <= row; row_offset++) {
            int old = queen_column[row - row_offset];
            int diff = old - col;
            if ((diff == 0) || diff == row_offset || diff == -row_offset) {
              break;
            }
          }
          if (row_offset <= row) { // From early break above
            continue; // ADD
          }
          if (row == ROW_N - 1) {
            count++;
            // print_solution(ROW_N, queen_column, col); // Print, then change state.
            row--;
          } else {
            parity[(row ^ col)&1]++; // Count parity for later optimization (stub code)
            queen_column[row++] = col;
          }
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    printf("%lld SOLUTIONS (%dx%d)\n", count, ROW_N, COL_N);
  }
  return 0;
}
1 SOLUTIONS (1x1)
0 SOLUTIONS (2x2)
0 SOLUTIONS (3x3)
2 SOLUTIONS (4x4)
10 SOLUTIONS (5x5)
4 SOLUTIONS (6x6)
40 SOLUTIONS (7x7)
92 SOLUTIONS (8x8)
```

---

**Other idea to speed things up**

1. Keep track of the count of queen placement on black (and/or white) squares.  Once that exceeds about half of `N`, time to unwind as subsequent forward iterations will all fail.
2. Look for patterns.  Example: Symmetry.  A solution that starts with the first queen on column 0 will have as many solutions as column `N-1`.  Looks like run time can be halved in some fashion.

Comment: I DID rewrite the loop - dropped it, see answer. Now there is mostly lf-else, and this makes it more state-machiney.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> void pr_solution(int *bq, int col) {
> void init_board(int bq[], int v) {
> ```

These could be declared with `static` linkage.

---

> ```
> int main() {
> ```

Prefer `int main(void)` to make this declaration a prototype (takes no arguments, rather than unspecified arguments).

---

> ```
> int row, col, rd, old;
> ```

All of these could have smaller scope.  E.g.

```
for (int row = 0; row >= 0;) {
```

It's always best to declare and initialise at the same time, rather than leaving a window where the variable exists but is not initialised.

---

> ```
>                 //pr_solution(bq, col);
> ```

Commented-out code is prone to becoming inconsistent.  Either remove it, or uncomment it (and perhaps provide a command-line argument to enable/disable).

Answer (score 1):

The second for-loop does so little, it can be replaced by a label, IF you stick with the `goto`:

```
for (row = 0; row >= 0;) {
    col = bq[row];
    NEXT_col:
    if (++col == N)
        bq[row--] = -1;
    else {
        for (rd = 1; rd <= row; rd++)
            if ((old = bq[row-rd]) == col || abs(old - col) == rd)
                goto NEXT_col;
        if (row == N - 1) {
            cnt++;
            row--;
        }
        else
            bq[row++] = col;
    }
}
```

No more `break` at the end. That was the *other* thing that for-loop did: getting broken at the end. The first thing was: being jumped at with `continue` (or `goto`).

I am quite happy now - it is still a "goto", but now it makes sense.

As they say about this N-Queens problem: **simple, but not trivial**.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that keeping track of the threats in a 2D-array is **twice as fast**. Now instead of incrementing the column, and checking later, the next column is found by a function.

The main loop is freed from the diagonal-checking. But now it has to add and also remove threats when a queen is moved.

```
/* Returns zeroed n*n array */
int **init_threats(int n) {
    int r;
    int **t2d = malloc(n * sizeof*t2d);
    for (r = 0; r < n; r++)
        t2d[r] = calloc(n, sizeof**t2d);
    return t2d;
}
/* Only needs a row from "threats[][]" */
int next_free(int *r, int after) {
    for (int c = after + 1; c < N; c++)
        if (r[c] == 0)
            return c;
    return -1;
}
/* Cumulative threats - they can overlap */
void change_thr(int chg, int r, int c, int **threats) {
    int tr, diag;
    for (tr = r + 1; tr < N; tr++) { 
        threats[tr][c] += chg;
        diag = c + tr - r;
        if (diag < N)
            threats[tr][diag] += chg;  
        diag = c - (tr - r);
        if (diag >= 0)
            threats[tr][diag] += chg;  
    }
}
int main() {
    int queen[N];
    init_board(queen, -1);  
    int **threats = init_threats(N);
    int row = 0, cnt = 0;
    int col;
    while (row >= 0) {
        col = next_free(threats[row], queen[row]);
        if (row == N - 1) { 
            if (col >= 0) 
                cnt++;
            row--;
        } else {
            if (queen[row] >= 0)
                change_thr(-1, row, queen[row], threats);   
            if (col >= 0) {
                change_thr(1, row, col, threats);   
                queen[row++] = col;
            } else 
                queen[row--] = -1;
        }
    }   
    printf("%d SOLUTIONS (%d-Queens)\n", cnt, N);
    return 0;
}
```